# Using HTMLUnit for Google Patents (patents.google.com)

Tags: java, htmlunit

I'm trying to crawl Google Patents DB. My problem is HTMLUnit doesn't get the complete page back. It seems that it only gets to the "Sign in" Button and ends.

I'm trying to parse the following [Website](https://patents.google.com/?assignee=Mannesmann&before=20010101&after=priority:19870101&clustered=false&sort=old).

My Code "currentpage.asText()" only gets:
Google Patents
Sign in

Can anybody help me or had an similar problem?

```
public class HTMLUnitGoogle3 {
@Test
public void patentPage() throws  ParseException, InterruptedException, IOException{

    HashMap<String, String> patente = new HashMap<String,String>();


    // Abfragezeitraum
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");

    // Daten
    Date startDate = df.parse("19870101");
    Date endDate = df.parse("19880101");
    String unternehmen = "Mannesmann";


    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTime(startDate);
    c.add(Calendar.MONTH, 3);
    Date tempDate = c.getTime();

    System.out.println("Vor der While - Datum: " + df.format(startDate) + " " + df.format(tempDate) + " " + df.format(endDate));

    // Erstelle eine Liste mit Links zu den Patenten auf der Seite
    ArrayList<String> ergebnisList = new ArrayList<String>();


    while(endDate.after(tempDate) || endDate.equals(tempDate)){
        // Aufbau der Umgebung

        System.out.println("Datum: " + df.format(startDate) + " " + df.format(tempDate) + " " + df.format(endDate));

        int seitenzaehler = 0; 
        String seite = ""; 
        boolean weitereSeite = true;

        while(weitereSeite){
            // Aufruf der Seite
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER);

            HtmlPage currentPage = seitenAufbau(webClient, df.format(startDate), df.format(tempDate), unternehmen, seite);

            System.out.println(currentPage.asText());

              listAllDivAnchors(currentPage);
              List<?> ws = currentPage.getByXPath("//search-results");
              for(int i = 0; i<ws.size();i++){
                  System.out.println(ws.get(i).toString());
              }

             HtmlHeading1 h1Title = (HtmlHeading1) currentPage.getElementById("title");
             System.out.println("Seite = " + h1Title.asText());
             HtmlAnchor weiter =  currentPage.getHtmlElementById("nextResult");

            currentPage.cleanUp();
            webClient.close();
            webClient = null;
        }

        // Addiere 3 Monate auf start und endDate
        startDate = tempDate; 
        Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        c1.setTime(tempDate);
        c1.add(Calendar.MONTH, 3);
        tempDate = c1.getTime();
        System.out.println("Neues Datum: " + df.format(startDate) + " " + df.format(tempDate) + " " + df.format(endDate));
    }
}

private void listAllDivAnchors(HtmlPage currentPage) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      List<?> divs = currentPage.getByXPath("//div");
      System.out.println("Divs Size: " + divs.size());
      for(int i = 0; i<divs.size();i++){
          System.out.println(divs.get(i).toString());
      }
      List<?> ii = currentPage.getByXPath("//a");
      for(int i = 0; i<ii.size();i++){
          System.out.println(ii.get(i).toString());
      }
      List<?> i2 = currentPage.getByXPath("//input");
      for(int i = 0; i<i2.size();i++){
          System.out.println(i2.get(i).toString());
      }
}
public HtmlPage seitenAufbau(WebClient webClient,String start , String ende, String unternehmen, String seite) throws InterruptedException{
    HtmlPage page = null;
    String link =       "https://patents.google.com/?"+
            "assignee="+ unternehmen
            +"&before="+ ende +
            "&after=priority:" + start +
            "&clustered=false"
            + "&sort=old" 
            + seite;
    System.out.println(link);
    try {
            webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF); 
            webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
            webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
            webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(80000);
            page = webClient.getPage(link);         

    } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("ex");
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JavaScriptJobManager manager = page.getEnclosingWindow().getJobManager();
    while (manager.getJobCount() > 0) {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    return page;
}
```

If I remove the throwExceptionOnScriptError I get the HTMLUnit Error:

```
======= EXCEPTION START ========
EcmaError: lineNumber=[11] column=[0] lineSource=[<no source>] name=[TypeError] sourceName=[gstatic.com/patent-search/frontend/patent-search.search_20160829_RC02/scs/compiled_dir/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js] message=[TypeError: Expected argument of type object, but instead had type object (...
```